# Wrapping Provider in same component throws Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got: object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, mobx

I wrote a simple counter example in both Mobx & Redux & it works

Full demo is available https://codesandbox.io/s/nw303w6jxl

But if I remove `Provider` from `./src/index.js`

```
const App = () => (
  <div className="container">
    <Mobx />
    <hr />
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Redux />
    </Provider>
  </div>
);
```

& put it in `./src/redux.js` while default exporting it throws an error

```
export default (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectReduxApp />
  </Provider>
);
```

> Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected
>   a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got: object

Its working but I don't know why its happening? I checked the `typeof` the default exported function from `./src/redux.js` ,i.e,

```
console.log(
    typeof(
       <Provider store={store}>
         <ConnectReduxApp />
       </Provider>
    )
);
```

& its an `object` but what if I want to use Redux only in a part of my React Application. Lets say a form. Then by this way it will throw an error. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because you're exporting not a function returning JSX nor a class with a render method that returns JSX, you're exporting JSX itself.

Either render it like `{reduxImported}`:

```
import reduxImported from './src/redux.js'
...
render() {
  <Container>
    {reduxImported}
    <MobX />
  </Container>
}
```

Or change your export to:

```
export default () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectReduxApp />
  </Provider>
)
```